# How to print neural networks in rmarkdown

Tags: r, neural-network, r-markdown

I am working with neural networks using the `neuralnet` package. In an R script I can print and visualize the result of my neural network just fine by using the `plot()` command, but when I try to do it in R markdown it does not print the network.

As an example, this is how I build the network:

```
library(ISLR)
data("College")
maxs <- apply(College[,2:18], 2, max)
mins <- apply(College[,2:18], 2, min)
scaled.data <- as.data.frame(scale(College[,2:18], center = mins, scale = maxs - mins))
Private = as.numeric(College$Private)-1
data0 = cbind(Private,scaled.data)
feats <- names(scaled.data)
f <- paste(feats,collapse=' + ')
f <- paste('Private ~',f)
f <- as.formula(f)
library(neuralnet)
nn <- neuralnet(f,data0,hidden=c(10,10,10),linear.output=FALSE)
plot(nn)
```

The code runs perfect, but the last line in R-markdown does not print the neural network.

Comment: Please add your the code or what you have tried so far.

Comment: I just edited the post

Comment: According to the following answer using `plot(nn, rep = "best")` does work (it does for me) (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39692235/plot-neural-net-work)

Comment: It works, thank you.